Why is the @event-click Function in v-calendar not working?
I want to trigger a function when clicking on an Event in the v-calendar by using @event-click. However the function is not triggert. I also don't get any console output like errors, etc.
@event-click use
<v-calendar
          ref="calendar"
          v-model="value"
          :weekdays="weekday"
          :type="type"
          :events="events"
          :event-overlap-mode="mode"
          :event-overlap-threshold="30"
          :event-color="getEventColor"
          @change="fetchEvents"
          @event-click="openEventDialog"
          locale="de"
          first-day-of-week="1"> 
...

Function which should be triggert:
openEventDialog({event}) {
      console.log("OPENEVBENTDIALOG", event)
      this.form = {...event};
      this.editDialog = true;
    },
...

I already tried to debug in different ways but nothing worked.

Where exactly did you see that there's supposed to be a @event-click event?
If I'm reading the documentation right I don't see any such event listed in there: https://vcalendar.io/calendar/api.html

I think of was in an YT Tutorial, however do you have an Idea how I can make an click-event when clicking on an entry in the calendar?
